# More efficient way than 'using UserID in (1,2,3 ...)'

Tags: sql

I have this query were a large number of IDs(close to 2000 of them) need to be queried. But it is not efficient at all. (takes a few seconds)

```
select * from tblABC where UserID in (2,3,123... )
```

So, basically there is this large number of UserIDs I have to deal with, so what would be a more efficient way of deal with it than using '`where UserID in (2,3,123... )`'

Using Microsoft SQL

Comment: Are the IDs also in a table or where are they coming from?

Comment: The ids are provided by a different api.

Comment: Create a temporary table with those id values. Join with that table.

Comment: Tag dbms used. Performance questions are usually product specific!

Comment: `join` to a `values (..)` clause containing the IDs

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you need to create a lookup table that has all ids and join with it

```
select t1.* from tblABC t1 inner join looup_table t2
on t1.UserId=t2.UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

First, returning 2,000 (or more) rows may take some time.  This would be particularly true if the rows are wide (lots of data per row).

Second, you should have an index on the column used for the `IN`:

```
create index on idx_tblABC_UserId on tblABC(UserId);
```

Third, the parsing and compiling of a query that is several 10k bytes in length may not be trivial.  You don't specify the database, but this *could* be a consideration.  Usually, this stage of query processing is not significant.

Fourth, even with an index, the query engine may decide to do a full table scan depending on the size of the table and the frequency of the ids in the `IN` list.

Fifth, if the ids are coming from the database, then you should not move them to the application layer to construct and `IN` clause.  You should be doing all the work in the database.

If you do the work in the database, I think the best query would be:

```
select a.*
from tblABC a
where exists (select 1 from ids where ids.UserId = a.UserId);
```